How does Wikipedia talk pages do comment threading?
There is a Wikipedia talk page and I would like to reply to it. How does Wiki Markup do threading, I tried using 2 and 4 spaces and that failed.

Like this,
Here is OT you want to reply to. - [[User:EvanCarroll|Evan Carroll]] ([[User talk:EvanCarroll|talk]]) 18:02, 3 April 2024 (UTC)

Then you'll to comment like this,
: Here is my new statement, one line below and after a colon `: `
to indicate it's a reply to the above. I sign it by appending
`~~~~` at the end of my reply. ~~~~

